Parameter 'function' of the transform datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset._map_single couldn't be hashed properly, a random hash was used instead
I have a function to pre-process the dataset before tokenization. Here is the code:
source_lang = "en"
target_lang = "fr"
def preprocess_dataset(examples):
    inputs = [example[source_lang] for example in examples["translation"]]
    targets = [example[target_lang] for example in examples["translation"]]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, return_tensors="pt", text_target=targets, padding="max_length", max_length=200, truncation=True)
    return model_inputs

and to call the function using .map():
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_dataset, batched=True)

The warning message is shown:
Parameter 'function'=<function preprocess_dataset at 0x7f968c4d4790> of the transform datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset._map_single couldn't be hashed properly, a random hash was used instead. Make sure your transforms and parameters are serializable with pickle or dill for the dataset fingerprinting and caching to work. If you reuse this transform, the caching mechanism will consider it to be different from the previous calls and recompute everything. This warning is only showed once. Subsequent hashing failures won't be showed.

What have I done wrong? How can I avoid this warning?
p.s. the subsequent training process can be done even if the warning appears.
p.s. the dataset is in JSON strings format, example data is as follows:
{"translation": {"en": "Hello", "fr": "Bonjour"}}
{"translation": {"en": "Enjoy your meal", "fr": "bon appétit"}}
{"translation": {"en": "Please", "fr": "s'il te plaît"}}

